# Filter lists based on user permissions

Tags: permissions, filter

I am following this [guide](http://sharepointlogics.com/2014/02/how-to-filter-sharepoint-list-based-on.html) to help me solve my problem. However, it is causing issues when I try to save the edited code in SharePoint Designer. I would greatly appreciate If someone could help me resolve this or come up with an easier solution to my problem.

This is the error that shows up:

> soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.Cannot complete this action. Please try again.0x80004005

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use something easier, like allowing folders in your list, then setting permissions for each folder.